# Handling API Response Structure with Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, frontend

I'm working on a React application where I'm making an Axios GET request to an API endpoint to fetch user data. However, I'm encountering an issue with handling the API response structure. The API response structure is as follows:

```
 {
  "success": true,
  "message": "Users retrieved successfully",
  "data": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "9a0fd1d9-efde-44e7-84fc-60112a7ece74",
        "name": "Admin User",
        // ... (other user properties)
      },
      // ... (more user objects)
    ],
    // ... (pagination and metadata)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to extract the user data from the "data" property within the "data" object and set it in my React component's state as a table
Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
axios
  .get(apiUrl, { headers })
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.data && response.data.data && Array.isArray(response.data.data)) {
      const dataArray = response.data.data;
      setUserData(dataArray);
    } else {
      console.error("API response data is not in the expected format:", response.data);
      // Handle the case where the data is not in the expected format
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
  });`
```

However, I'm still getting the error message "API response data is not an array or does not contain the 'data' property."

Can someone help me understand what might be going wrong with my code or suggest a better way to handle this API response structure in React?
Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: because you need to refer `response.data.data.data` since by default `response.data` is the data of the response object and then you have two levels to go inside.